# Case insensitive ordering for citext field type in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-order-by

Migration File.

```
class ChangeDataTypeOrganisationName < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    enable_extension :citext
    change_column :organisations, :name, :citext
  end
  
  def down
    change_column :organisations, :name, :text
    disable_extension :citext
  end
end
```

index.json.jbuilder

```
json.offices_filters @offices.order(:name) do |office|
  json.(office, :id, :name)
end
```

I want to order the offices_filter based on the offices name. I had field type for office name as text so just to make it case-insensitive I changed the data type to citext just to perform case-insensitve ordering. But the ordering is still case-sensitive. First offices are orders which lower case and then upper case officers are ordered. Please help me resolve this issue.

Update 1

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "offices"
LINE 1: ...$1) ORDER BY "organisations"."updated_at" DESC, LOWER(offices.na...
```

Update 2

organisations_controller.rb

```
def index
 @offices = Organisation.all
 @offices = offices.order(updated_at: :desc)
end
```

Update 3

```
Ankor
asdas
John Wilson
Abp
Sim Limited
```

Comment: Well, what it says, is not finding the `offices` table in your query, indeed it seems to be using `organisations` in the query as order parameter. Are you sure that `@offices` is really a collection of `Office` models? Could you add the relevant code where you're getting that `@offices` variable?

Comment: @AlterLagos Please check update 2. I am getting offices from organisation model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try with:

```
@offices.order('LOWER(organisations.name)')
```

Comment: PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "name" is ambiguous

I get this error

Comment: Please check update 1 in the question. thats the new error

Comment: Please check update 3, there was no error but the output is not ordered.

Comment: @user12763413 but that's because you're ordering by `updated_at` first, remove that and it should work.